# Documentation Tools: Prevent rasterizing output cell

Tags: documentation, workbench

When building documentation using the Workbench, some of the output cells get fully rasterized.  I assume this is done to save space.

[image]

Can I turn this off, either globally, or on a per-cell basis?  I want to keep certain output as vector graphics.

Comment: See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28316/creating-cross-version-compatible-documentation-with-workbench/28592?noredirect=1#comment338293_28592) and all comments that follow.

Comment: @QuantumDot Would you like to summarize that in an answer?

Comment: In [`buildDocumentation`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/131569/14303) I've added `"ConvertGraphicsToBitmaps"` option. It doesn't do anything sophisticated, on `False` it just `Block`s `ConvertGraphicsToBitmaps` function and replaces it with function doing nothing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know any option that would control this behavior, but there are hacks that can completely prevent this rasterization.

Rasterization is performed by `ConvertGraphicsToBitmaps` function from `` DocumentationBuild`Common` `` package. This function performs rasterization of output cells from given `NotebookObject` and returns `Null`, that's all it does, so we can safely override it with function that only returns `Null`.

For this override to take effect during documentation build, governed by `docbuild.xml` file, we can add following code, right before `<ant antfile="${appPath}/DocumentationBuild/SystemFiles/ant/Build/notebook.xml"` line:

```ant
<mathematica exe="${mathExe}">
    <![CDATA[
        If[Not@MemberQ[$Path, #], PrependTo[$Path, #]]&@AntProperty["appPath"]
        Needs@"DocumentationBuild`"
        ConvertGraphicsToBitmaps = Null&
    ]]> 
</mathematica>
```

First line adds directory containing documentation building packages to `$Path` (this directory is stored in Ant `"appPath"` property), second line loads `` DocumentationBuild` `` package, third overrides relevant function.

Comment: Thanks, very useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132294/12